# The device is locked. Enter the passcode

Tags: usb, iphone

I sometimes plug my iPhone to my Ubuntu laptop just to charge it.
I'm not trying to sync or anything, just charge.

I get the message "The device '...' is locked. Enter the passcode on the device and click 'Try again'".

I don't want to unlock, I just want to charge. Clicking Cancel opens the popup again in a loop.

Tired, I decided to unlock it just to leave me alone... but I instead got a mount error and the popup came back in the loop.

I just want to charge!!

Answer (score 1):

**Configuring Automounting**

To enable or disable automount open a terminal and type dconf-editor followed by the [Enter] key.
Browse to `org/gnome/desktop/media-handling`. The automount key controls whether to automatically mount media. If set to `true`, then Nautilus will automatically mount media such as user-visible hard disks and removable media on start-up and media insertion.

There is another key, `org/gnome/desktop/media-handling/automount-open`. This controls whether to automatically open a folder for automounted media. If set to `true`, then Nautilus will automatically open a folder when media is automounted. This only applies to media where no known x-content/* type was detected; for media where a known x-content type is detected, the user configurable action will be taken instead.

Turning both of these values to false should stop the problem.

Comment: Cheers! Will this prevent USB drives from automounting too? If so, is it possible to prevent the *device locked* prompt but allow USB drives to mount fine?

Comment: @alex It works the same for USB drives, as all USB devices that provide mass-storage options are treated in the same way.